# Calculate energy field for 2D burgers equation in matalb

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the energy field of the 2D Burgers equation using the following formula:

[image: Formula]

Can anyone help me how I can implement that in Matlab.I have the matrices for u,v.

Comment: What have you have tried so far? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, it was recommended to use Simpson quadratures to integrate equations (the `quad` method). Now Matlab has the `integral` method:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html

In particular, for your case, you want the `integral2` method:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html

From looking at the wiki page for [Burger's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation) it isn't clear to me what `u` is. To use these methods, you must have an explicit form of u in terms of the integration variables.